# Probability Question : Pick a ball.

Tags: probability

Here's the problem statement.

> Given a bag with three type of balls, i.e. winning ball, losing ball and try-again ball. If a person picks up a winning ball then he wins, if he picks losing ball then he loses and if he picks a try-again ball, he tries again and that try-again ball is discarded. Now, if there are w,l and t numbers of winning,losing and try-again balls in bag, respectively. What is the probability that the person wins.

Here's the simple solution.

Either Pick the winning ball or pick try again ball, and then pick winning ball, or pick try again ball two times and then pick a winning ball.. and so on.. till there are no more try-again balls available.

The equation would be of the type

Let Total (o) = w+l+t

```
Prob = w/o + (t/o)*(w/(o-1)) + (t/o)*(t-1/o-1)*(w/o-2) ..
```

Now, this is actualle equivalent to w/(w+l), i.e. as if there were no try-again at all.and the try-again actually plays no role.

Now, I am not able to get my head around the fact that why does the try-again thing plays no role at all?

Comment: What do you mean it's equivalent to w/o? Without the try again balls the probability would simply be $\frac{w}{o}$, how is that equivalent?

Comment: @ZettaSuro Yeah my bad, edited. It is w/w+l

Comment: The try-again option affects the number of picks before a decision is made, but it doesn't change the win/lose balance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conditional probability of winning or losing on a given draw, *given he does not choose a try-again ball*, only depends on the relative number of win or lose balls.  Therefore, the last draw he makes, which determines the outcome of the game, only depends on the number of win and lose balls.